# How do I remove a null elements from a JSONArray?

Tags: android, arrays

I am trying to remove null objects from my `JsonArray`. I have a `ListView` where I select some items using `CheckBox`.

Checked items need to be added to the `JsonArray` and unchecked items need to  removed from the `JsonArray`.

I wrote the below code for this but
unchecked items are not removing from JsonArray coming as `null` objects.

### Code:

```
try {

    rootObj = new JSONObject();
    rootObj.put("UserName", UserSharedPreferences.getPreferenceString(Constants.USER_NAME, null));

    JSONArray itemsArray = new JSONArray();

    ArrayList<RaisePoBean> raisePoBeantemplist = new ArrayList(raisePoBeanArrayList);

    for (int i = 0; i < raisePoBeantemplist.size(); i++) {

        if (raisePoBeantemplist.get(i).isCheck()) {

            JSONObject itemsObj = new JSONObject();
            itemsObj.put("ItemCode", raisePoBeantemplist.get(i).getItemName());
            itemsObj.put("ItemName", raisePoBeantemplist.get(i)
                    .getItemCode());
            itemsObj.put("Qty", "" + raisePoBeantemplist.get(i).getQty());
            itemsObj.put("Rate", "" + raisePoBeantemplist.get(i).getRate());
            itemsObj.put("Category", raisePoBeantemplist.get(i).getCatogory());
            itemsObj.put("WantDate", raisePoBeantemplist.get(i).getDate());
            itemsArray.put(i, itemsObj);
        }
    }
    rootObje.put("model",itemsObj);
    System.out.println("Final object is====>" + rootObj.toString());
} catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line below is defining specific indexes for the items

```
itemsArray.put(i, itemsObj); // Put item at specific index
```

Instead only add items to the end

```
itemsArray.put(itemsObj);  // Put items at end of array
```

Comment: so what shuld i chnage finally?

Comment: Change the first line to the second line.

Comment: then this line only not adding unchecked items in my Json Array?

Comment: i mean unchecked items adding in my JSONArray as null,That's why i want to remove the null objects from my JsonArray

Comment: Why don't you try it? It involves deleting 3 character and running your code.

Comment: when i tapped on submit buutton then above code is executing and adding details in JsonArry